# Exporting a library for webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, integration

So for a project I want to start using reactjs but unfortunately the current project doesn't have a build pipeline. I think for now I can just set up a build pipeline using WebPack, Babel, and Sass and compile that all into a bundle, let's call that `bundle.js`.  I can link that compiled javascript file into one of our rendered pages and then my goal is to export the component somehow so that I can create it using the following function.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyExportedComponent, {prop: 'prop'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What would be the proper way to export the class?

Is `export default MyExportedComponent` enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the WebPack config to export the code as a bundle.

Here is the exported bundle in the main compiled JavaScript file

`exportedLibary.js`

```
module.exports = {
    someRender: (element) => {
        ReactDom.render(
             <div>Hello</div>
        );
    }
}
```

And making modifications to the output parameter in the WebPack config file:

`webpack.config.js`

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'someDir'),
    library: 'RenderComponent'
}
```

Now we can use the exported library in any of our projects.

`someProject.html`

```
<script src="someDir/bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would call `ReactDOM.render()` inside your bundle.js, usually in the file that represents the entry point to your bundle.

This means, you don't have to export anything, and can just embed bundle.js into your HTML file.

---

If you *need* to export something from your bundle, you could attach it to the global scope by setting an attribute on `window`. You should try to avoid that though.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that right now they are rendering everything using their own functions in a separate js file that is not being compiled. I need to be able to change that separate js file and render within their render function.